# Kotlin edittext editable to string returns nothing

Tags: android, kotlin

Does anyone experience this?

I am trying to get the input value from an editText. I did the following.

```
val input = edittext_input.text.toString()
```

However the result is nothing. I tried logging edittext_input.text and it has a value. Do you guys have an idea why is this happening. Is it a bug on kotlin?

One workaround I found is this.

```
val input = "${edittext_input.text}"
```

**UPDATE:**
Actual Full Code:

```
private fun setupUI() {

    val inputTestText = (findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_username)).text
    val inputTestTextToString: String = 100.toString()

    val userInput: String = edittext_username.text.toString()
    val passInput = "${edittext_password.text}"

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_login).setOnClickListener {

        Log.i(TAG, "inputTestText is null? ${inputTestText == null}")
        Log.i(TAG, "inputTestTextToString: $inputTestTextToString")

        Log.i(TAG, "A user: $userInput password: $passInput")
        Log.i(TAG, "B user: ${edittext_username.text} password: ${edittext_password.text}")

    }
}
```

Result:

```
inputTestText is null? false
inputTestTextToString: 100
A user:  password:
B user: test password: test
```

Comment: what kotlin version you are using?

Comment: The two calls you have in your examples should have identical results... How did you log the value you've mentioned?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem I guess. See log carefully

Comment: @zsmb13 I log the values like the following:
Log.i(TAG, "INPUT: $input") -> This results to nothing
Log.i(TAG, "INPUT: ${edittext_input.text}" -> This show the correct value
Log.i(TAG, "INPUT: ${edittext_input.text.toString}" -> No value

Comment: @Exigente05 Yes thats what I thought to. It should't have no problem at all. That is why it is really weird.

Comment: @Exigente05 I am using Kotlin v1.2

Comment: I have used same code and tried to figure out testing multiple criteria but it works all time. If you still facing same problem please post code in detail with log printing

Comment: @Exigente05 I provided the actual code I have here with some experiments and tests logs in it.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning values before onClickListener by,

```
val inputTestText = (findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edittext_username)).text
val inputTestTextToString: String = 100.toString()

val userInput: String = edittext_username.text.toString()
val passInput = "${edittext_password.text}"
```

And printing values inside button click listener,

Here, variables get empty values because there is no text initially. After putting something you are clicking on button so its showing empty values. And `${edittext_username.text}` by this you are getting values from edittext field.

You just need to put assignment lines inside onClickListener.

Final code should be,

```
findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_login).setOnClickListener {

    val userInput: String = edittext_username.text.toString()
    val passInput = "${edittext_password.text}"
    //put above two line here

    Log.i(TAG, "inputTestText is null? ${inputTestText == null}")
    Log.i(TAG, "inputTestTextToString: $inputTestTextToString")

    Log.i(TAG, "A user: $userInput password: $passInput")
    Log.i(TAG, "B user: ${edittext_username.text} password: ${edittext_password.text}")

}
```

Comment: Thanks. Dumb me :(